# firebase query returning partially updated node on client

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

For some reasons I'm having a bug I'm not able to reproduce

I'm firing a new Firebase Query based on current timestamp each time I receive added/updated/removed data

one node has this schema

```
$UID:
  color:
  description:
  infos:
  temperature :
    low:
    high:
  timestamp:
  title:
  update:
```

So in my app I move a graphic object with the mouse and update values to db as so:

```
this.editor.updates[`${this.uid}/update`] = true;
this.editor.updates[`${this.uid}/add`] = null;
this.editor.updates[`${this.uid}/infos`] = "my new infos";
this.editor.updates[`${this.uid}/timestamp`] = Date.now();
// then I send `this.editor.updates` object to the realtime database
```

the listener I'm using is `snapshotChanges` so instantly it retrieves an object of eventType `child_added`

this could be normal as this is the first value emitted to the listener, but the only problem is I get a partial object containing only the updated properties `infos`, `timestamp` and `update` where the object should also contain `temperature`, `color`, `title` and `description`.

Looks like the problem might come from the fact I instantely trigger back a new query inside subscription which leads in strange behavior. Here is my recursive query

inside ngOnInit of my main component

```
public date$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
...
this.date$.pipe(
  switchMap(
    (date) => {
      this.currQuery = this.db.getActionsStartAtNow('path', date)
      return (this.currQuery);
    }
  )
).subscribe(
  (actionsList:any[]) => {
    //process the data
    //then trigger updated query
    this.date$.next(Date.now())
  }
)
```

and in my database service

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';

  constructor(private db:AngularFireDatabase) {
  }


...

  getActionsStartAtNow(path:string, date?:number){ 
    return (date ? this.db.list(path, (ref) => {
          return (ref.orderByChild('timestamp').startAt(date))
        }
      ).snapshotChanges() : Observable.empty()
    )
  }
```

wrong log

> Object { infos: "0-1602194400000-1602626400000-0-0-1-0", timestamp: 1605429748370, update: true }

correct log

> Object { color: 3, description: "", infos: "0-1602194400000-1602626400000-0-0-1-0", temperature: {…}, timestamp: 1605429748370, title: "", update: true }

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what problem you have. Can you replace your description of what your code does, with the actual code for those writes, and then in your listener log the output that you don't expect?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'll do that but basically my problem is I retrieve only the updated values + whole updated node in the listener where I should only retrieve the whole update node

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've just edited my post with the requested infos. sorry if that's not 100% of the original code but I kept the interesting part. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, but there's too much going on here for me to see what the problem is. Can you reproduce the problem in isolation, for example by starting fro scratch i a site like jsbin/stackblitz?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'll try do that. appart from me doing that do you have any idea why an update value returns a  'child_added` event and why I could be retrieving a partial node. Still I'll try reproduce the error ...? thanks

Comment: Nope, no idea right now. I don't see you listening to `child_` anywhere, which also makes it hard to debug the issue. Hence asking for a minimal repro. You might want to start that repro without AngularFire, as it'd make a big difference if you don't need to that reproduce it (or knowing that it can't be reproduced without it).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks again for your helped you really helped me out for any other questions I had, unfortunately I was unable to reproduce the erro I've made a stackblitz and everything is fine with my test. I'm making a graphic editor with canvas first itme I move the object everything is fine second time error third time ... everything is fine. What is strange is I'm can't see why it would come from my code as the response is from server. I've also tried watching on the server I one of my command deletes the node but nothing like this shows, just a simple update. really strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224575/discussion-between-jsmith-and-frank-van-puffelen).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've just added a comment in the chat also I've updated my whole post to make it clearer as I was unable to reproduce the error. Sorry for the long talking, I'm really stuck. Thanks

Comment: The code that creates the `updates` JSON, only sets `update`, `add`, `infos`, and `timestamp`. So if the `this.uid` node doesn't exist yet, and that's all you write, you'll get a `child_added` with just those properties. If you later add more properties to `this.uid`, you'll then get a `child_changed` with the original and the new properties.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'll try find a workaround but obviously I can't understand the logic behing this. My node is already created and when creating it everything works fine. it's when I change it that I get child_added instead of child_changed. So I'll try find a workaround. Still many thanks for your help whish it had been easier.

Comment: I just don't see where you're attaching a listener to the database, which makes it hard to help further.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen just added an edit to my post

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't see what's going wrong there. At this point I'm out of ideas, so unless you can reproduce the problem somewhere where I can see it in action, it'll be hard to help further. Hopefully somebody else spots what's going on in that case.